# Why ie7 and google chrome display not similar , How to apply ie7 to google chrome view?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why ie7 and google chrome display not similar , How to apply ie7 to google chrome view ?

i try to work hard , but i can not do that , thank you for every answer. ^^

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/q7t15yjh/1/

```
<div style=" float: left; margin-left: 0px; ">
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute;display: block;color: #000;float: left;">
   <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d9a919813dac42adbd0e3106bc19bc04.png" style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 200px; width: 200px; opacity: 1;">
</div>

<div style=" width: 80px; height: 80px; float: left; ">
    <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/tiny-animals/256/cat-icon.png" width="80" height="80" style=" border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203); float: left;" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is because each browser handles CSS in different ways. However, I wouldn't worry about IE7 at all, it's absolutely outdated and whoever uses it is aware of that

Comment: http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/11/11/ie-7-quirks-floats-and-margins/

Comment: What do you mean "How to apply ie7 to google chrome view"? You want to display your website in Chrome with the IE7 view engine? So, take a look at [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd), please. It might what you've been searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser behaves different with html and css codes
specially IE that has many bugs due to css
Most of the times IE displays the css  in a wrong way
It's better not to care about IE7 at all...
but you see the fiddle is shown the same in FF and Chrome